# Как закрасить ячейку со значением максимума двумерного массива c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, c#-7.3

У меня есть двумерный массив случайных целых чисел, которые находятся в массиве текстбоксов. Я нашла максимум и вывела его на Label1. Все получилось. Но мне еще нужно закрасить цветом тот тектбокс, в котором находится этот максимум. У меня были версии, но неудачные. Помогите пожалуйста, кто знает, где тут ошибка?

```
int max = Convert.ToInt32(t[0, 0].Text);
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{

    for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(t[i, j].Text) > max)
        {
            max = Convert.ToInt32(t[i, j].Text);
            t[i, j].BackColor = Color.Red;
            label1.Text = "" + max;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Запоминайте x и y ячейки, если она максимальная. Или вообще сохраняйте ссылку на этот объект. По выходу из цикла,(здесь есть запятая?) устанавливайте цвет запомненной ячейке и значение этой ячейки полю label1. А ошибка у вас в следующем - вы закрашиваете все ячейки, большие первой ячейки.